# Answer in array when queried in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i am developing a reply to rest request, i am almost done but i cant finish the list of objects in the array. i have a code which returns me json
here is my code:

```
DECLARE
   v_count varchar2(2000);
   v_id                     USERS_C.id%TYPE;
   v_users_name             USERS_C.name%TYPE;
   v_organization_id varchar2(2000);
   v_organization_name      ORGANIZATIONS.NAME%TYPE;
   v_role varchar2(2000);


     CURSOR c_event IS SELECT
            id,
            users_name,
            organization_id,
            organization_name,
            role
                 FROM
                      (SELECT
                              a.*,
                              ROWNUM rnum
                FROM
                    (SELECT
                            ev.id,
                            ev.login users_name  ,
                            ds.id    organization_id,
                            ds.NAME  organization_name,
                            cv.role_names role


                        FROM ORGANIZATIONS_USERS lo
                              LEFT JOIN users_c ev ON ev.ID = lo.USER_ID
                              LEFT JOIN ORGANIZATIONS ds ON lo.ORGANIZATION_ID = ds.id
                              LEFT JOIN APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS cv ON ev.login = cv.USER_NAME
                        ) a
            );

BEGIN


         SELECT
                COUNT(*)
         INTO
                v_count
         FROM    users_c  ;
         IF v_count = 0 THEN

                apex_json.open_object;
                apex_json.write('success', false);
                apex_json.write('message', 'No data found');
                apex_json.write('count', 0);
                apex_json.close_object;
                return;
        END IF;
        OPEN c_event;
        apex_json.open_object;
        apex_json.write('count',v_count);
        apex_json.open_array('items');
        LOOP
            FETCH c_event INTO v_id,v_users_name,v_organization_id,v_organization_name,v_role;
            EXIT WHEN c_event%notfound;
            apex_json.open_object;
            apex_json.write('id', v_id);
            apex_json.write('user', v_users_name );
             apex_json.open_array('datasectors');
             apex_json.write('id', v_organization_id);
             apex_json.write('name', v_organization_name);
             apex_json.close_array;
            apex_json.open_object('roles');
            apex_json.write('role', v_role);
            apex_json.close_object;
            apex_json.close_object;
        END LOOP;
        apex_json.close_all;
        CLOSE c_event;
End;
```

he returns this answer:

```
 "items": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "user": "andrii",
      "datasectors": [
        "id": "21",
          "name": "TOW3"
      ],
      "roles": {
      "role": "Admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
       "user": "andrii",
      "datasectors": [
        "id": "122",
         "name": "TOW2""
      ],
      "roles": {
       "role": "Admin"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "user": "andrii",
      "datasectors": [
        "id": "62",
        "name": "TOW1""
      ],
      "roles": {
        "role": "Admin"
      }
```

you see, the number of my answers depends on the number of datasectors I am in.
I want everyone to be in arrays, that's right

```
    "items": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "user": "andrii",
          "datasectors": [{
            "id": "21",
              "name": "TOW3"
            },
            {
            "id": "122",
             "name": "TOW2""
            },
            {
            "id": "62",
            "name": "TOW1"
            }
          ],
          "roles": {
          "role": "Admin"
          }
        }
```

Here is a request for each I know of all the organizations that bind me

```
SELECT
             ds.id    organization_id,  
             ds.NAME  organization_name                        

    FROM ORGANIZATIONS_USERS lo
        LEFT JOIN users_c ev ON ev.ID = lo.USER_ID
         LEFT JOIN ORGANIZATIONS ds ON lo.ORGANIZATION_ID = ds.id
  where df.login = 'andrii'
```

and I have to put that answer in

```
apex_json.open_array('datasectors');
apex_json.write('id', v_organization_id);
apex_json.write('name', v_organization_name);
apex_json.close_array;
```

My table

```html
Table :users_c

id      login 
2       Andrii
3       Ira

Table :ORGANIZATIONS_USERS
id       USER_ID    ORGANIZATION_ID
1        2          21
2        2          122
3        2          62
4        3          122
5        3          62

Table :ORGANIZATIONS
id       Name    
21       Tow1          
122      Tow2
62       Tom3
      Table : APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS 
   USER_NAME     ROLE_NAMES
   Andrii       Admіn, Operator
   Ira          Admіn
```

Comment: in reply to me [{
         "id": "82",
         "name": "MTMG"
}

Comment: may be
datasectors ": [{
         "id": "82",
         "name": "MTMG"
}
         "id": "83",
         "name": "MTMG1"
{

Comment: but depending on the response to "SELECT
              ds.id organization_id,
              ds.NAME organization_name
        
     FROM ORGANIZATIONS_USERS lo
         LEFT JOIN users_c ev ON ev.ID = lo.USER_ID
          LEFT JOIN ORGANIZATIONS ds ON lo.ORGANIZATION_ID = ds.id
   where df.login = 'My name' "

Comment: well, give me 5 min, i will be grateful for your help

Comment: i changed the question, maybe this will help you understand

Comment: APC , can you help me?

Comment: What version of the database are you using?

Comment: i  using  version   18c

Comment: I see. Just so you know, you could use some newer SQL and PL/SQL options for generating JSON, but we'll stick with apex_json here since that's what you started with. The problem with your current solution is that you go into a loop. Inside the loop, you open the datasectors array, but in that iteration of the loop, you only have one datasector. You need all of them to be able to write them out. I'll try to provide an example, but because you haven't provided any DDL, I can't test it on my side.

Comment: i add my table for 2 uaers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basic idea:

```
declare

  v_count number;

begin

  select count(*)
  into v_count
  from users_c;

  if v_count = 0 then
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('success', false);
    apex_json.write('message', 'No data found');
    apex_json.write('count', 0);
    apex_json.close_object;

    return;
  end if;

  apex_json.open_object;
  apex_json.write('count', v_count);
  apex_json.open_array('items');

  for user_rec in (
    select id,
      login
    from users_c
  )
  loop
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('id', user_rec.id);
    apex_json.write('user', user_rec.login);
    apex_json.open_array('datasectors');

    for org_rec in (
      select id,
        name
      from organizations o
      where id in (
        select organization_id
        from organization_users
        where user_id = user_rec.id
      )
    )
    loop
      apex_json.open_object;
      apex_json.write('id', org_rec.id);
      apex_json.write('name', org_rec.name);
      apex_json.close_object;
    end loop;

    apex_json.close_array; -- datasectors
    apex_json.close_object;
  end loop;

  apex_json.close_array; -- items
  apex_json.close_object;

end;
```

If you're using ORDS on 18c, there's probably a better solution for you using SQL, but the above should work in general.

The only issue I can spot is that the first query that gets a count on users_c may get a different number than the second query on the same table. There are different ways you could address this, but I'll leave that exercise to you if it matters.

Have a look at this series for more options:
https://jsao.io/2015/07/relational-to-json-in-oracle-database/